# How to Mirror pose of hand in Daz3d

Tags: daz3d

Is there a way to mirror a hand pose in Daz3D (right hand to left hand)?

I have tried Symmetry but it's not working.

I am using Victoria4 and the Skeleton bundle...

thanks